# Restructure uploads directory for past months and years

Tags: wordpress, upload, media

I am looking for a way to restructure the WordPress uploads directory and instead of the default year/month, I would like to use year/month/day and probably even hour.

So far, I have managed to accomplish this by using the code snippet found here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/230694/make-default-upload-folder-year-month-day-wordpress-without-plugin

It actually works, but unfortunately this applies only to new media and not the old.

Also, is there a way to make WordPress store only media up to 1000 files (inodes) per directory?

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 questions so far:

- First, rename the old stuff: don't forget that renaming the uploaded files means you have to update the posts and pages where you have a reference to... Then have to look up in your database and do some replaces...
- Second, only 1000 files per directory. Then I suggest you should have a plugin that calculates the MD5 sum of the file and then use the first digits to divide rather than using dates...

A MD5 is like this: `8747e564eb53cb2f1dcb9aae0779c2aa` then you could have directories divided like this: `8/7/4/7/e/myfile.txt`. This will subdivise your directories having more or less an equal number of files based on characteristics of the MD5 algorithm. Using 5 subdirectories will dispatch your files in 1 million directories (16^5). Then using the first 4 chars means only 65500 directories.

But it is quite tricky question because I don't see the real problem to have many files in a single directory.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We are using a news aggregator to fetch news from various sources. We have multiple campaigns that run on a daily schedule. As a result, our media library gets populated very quickly and our hosting company suggested to trim down the media folders to 1024 files (inodes) per folder and apply a new file structure.